# AWS amplify error message: "You are not authorized to make this call."

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am configuring Amplify from this link: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start

I was able to push the data to DynamoDb via GraphQL "mutate" command, and was able to query successfully.

After two days i am again trying to perform same operation and getting error message "You are not authorized to make this call."

I checked and my API key has not expired.

AWS team, can you please help?

Comment: SO is not a place for getting support from product teams. It's for helping with problems with code. There is no code shown here, therefore I vote to close as off-topic for SO.

Comment: Yes, we can! Come join us on Discord. https://discord.com/invite/jWVbPfC I have also voted to close this question though, for the same reason cited by underscore_d.